# Typescript, JSON: Mapping nested array always returns empty

Tags: json, parsing, typescript, ionic2, http-get

I am new to typescript and trying to parse a JSON from a GET request which looks like this (removed some data):

```
{  
   "currency_rate":1,
   "data":[  
     {  
        "mapIdfrom":"oslo_no",
        "refr":false,
        "duration":{  
        "total":75300,
        "return":0,
        "departure":75300
     },
     "flyTo":"STR"
    }
   ]
}
```

I am getting the "currency_rate" for example, but the "data"-array is empty.

The GET request looks like this (only relevant parts) :

```
[...]
api_url = 'https://api.skypicker.com/flights';
[...]
let body =  {
              flyFrom: 'OSL',
              to: 'STR',
              dateFrom: '01%252F04%252F2017',
              dateTo: '20%2F04%2F2017',
              daysInDestinationFrom: 15,
              daysInDestinationTo: 20,
              returnFrom: '01%2F04%2F2017',
              returnTo: '20%2F04%2F2017',
              typeFlight: 'oneway',
              oneforcity: 0,
              one_per_date: 0,
              passengers: 1,
              adults: 1,
              children: 0,
              infants: 0,
              flyDays: '%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D',
              onlyWorkingDays: 0,
              directFlights: 0,
              partner: 'picky',
              partner_market: 'en',
              v: 2,
              xml: 0,
              curr: 'EUR',
              locale: 'en',
              price_from: 1,
              price_to: 10000,
              dtimefrom: '00%3A00',
              dtimeto: '00%3A00',
              atimefrom: '00%3A00',
              atimeto: '00%3A00',
              returndtimefrom: '00%3A00',
              returndtimeto: '00%3A00',
              returnatimefrom: '00%3A00',
              returnatimeto: '00%3A00',
              stopoverfrom: '00%3A00',
              stopoverto: '00%3A00',
              booking_token: 'hashed%20data',
              offset: 0,
              limit: 30,
              sort: 'price',
              asc: 1
            }

let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body)

return this.http.get(`${this.api_url}?${bodyString}`)
  .map(res => <SkyPickerFlight>res.json());
```

The model "SkyPickerFlight" is defined like this:

```
import { SkyPickerFlightData } from '../models/skyPickerFlightData';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export interface SkyPickerFlightI {
  currency: string;
  data: Observable<any[]>;
}
```

I have also tried replacing `data: Observable<any[]>` with `data: Observable<SkyPickerFlightData[]>`, the actual object, but also doesn't work.

Here you can get the full GET request:

```
https://api.skypicker.com/flights?flyFrom=OSL&to=STR&dateFrom=01%2F04%2F2017&dateTo=20%2F04%2F2017&daysInDestinationFrom=15&daysInDestinationTo=20&returnFrom=01%2F04%2F2017&returnTo=20%2F04%2F2017&typeFlight=oneway&oneforcity=0&one_per_date=0&passengers=1&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&flyDays=%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D&onlyWorkingDays=0&onlyWeekends=0&directFlights=0&partner=picky&partner_market=en&v=2&xml=0&curr=EUR&locale=en&price_from=1&price_to=10000&dtimefrom=00%3A00&dtimeto=00%3A00&atimefrom=00%3A00&atimeto=00%3A00&returndtimefrom=00%3A00&returndtimeto=00%3A00&returnatimefrom=00%3A00&returnatimeto=00%3A00&stopoverfrom=00%3A00&stopoverto=00%3A00&booking_token=hashed%20data&offset=0&limit=30&sort=price&asc=1
```

I am still looking into it but it looks like the GET request is a bit funky using `this.http.get(`${this.api_url}?${bodyString}`)` actually returns:

```
{"connections":[],"currency":"EUR","del":0,"time":1,"search_params":{"to_type":"anywhere","flyFrom_type":"anywhere","seats":{"infants":0,"passengers":1,"adults":1,"children":0}},"ref_tasks":{},"currency_rate":1.0,"data":[],"refresh":[]}
```

A different result than the GET request above. Not sure if I was clear. But trying the GET request like this (I will spare you with the long definition of the URLSearchParams) ends in a Bad Gateway error:

```
return this.http.get(this.api_url, {search: params})
  .map(res => res)
```

---- EDIT -----
It worked after I copy-pasted the entire URL in:

```
return this.http.get(<URL PASTED HERE>)
  .map(res => res)
```

Would still like to know how to pass the parameters in a clean way rather than pasting the entire URL in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the GET request. Using URLSearchParams/RequestOptions didnt work for some reason. Kept getting a 'BAD GATEWAY' error. So I passed the url directly in the http request like so:

```
this.http.get('https://api.skypicker.com/flights?' + bodyStringSerialized)
```

Using the below serialize function (another version of this function I found messed with the values of the param-values, so I removed the encoding). I used it likt this 'serialized(json, '')':

```
serialize(obj, prefix) {
var str = [], p;
for(p in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
    str.push((v !== null && typeof v === "object") ?
      this.serialize(v, k) :
      k + "=" + v);
  }
}
return str.join("&");
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A section of your json response would not be an Observable.

Try:

```
export interface SkyPickerFlightI {
  currency: string;
  data: any[];
}
```

You will get an `Observable<SkyPickerFlightI>` from http which would contain both `currency_rate` and `data`

Comment: Hey, 
thanks for the help. But unfortunately, that didn't do it either. Also tried with `data: SkyPickerFlightData[]`

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what are you trying to achieve by `data: Observable<any[]>;`. As @suraj said, "A section of your json response would not be an Observable".

As for the answer, I think you do not need to typecast the response into a typical Interface. A simple `.map(res => res.json());` would also work. I am assuming you need it like this, but, just saying to make it easier.

Not sure if problem exists there? So, you can do this and check if the data is coming to your GET :

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.http.get(`${this.api_url}?${bodyString}`)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log("Data : ", data);
            observer.next(data);
      },
      (err) => {
            console.log("Error : ", err);
            observer.error(err);
      });
});
```

Check if above logs the necessary data. If it does then check again by typecasting as you were doing in your code.

Now, here you are returning a new Observable to calling method. So, you will have to `subscribe()` in calling method as well.

Comment: Hi Sagar, thanks for your help as well. The data returned looks wrong. So it might be the GET request. I logged the URL-Request and it looks a bit different than usual and actually returns empty "data[]", too.

Comment: So problem is in get request then. Cool. I just put your get url in browser. The result is nowhere near what you are expecting format. But, I do find that `currency_rate` param in the result. I think you can access it in `console.log(data.currency_rate)` or `console.log(data['currency_rate'])`. To help you debug this, take the result from the browser output after putting this url and paste it in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ . Should help a little.